# How to set div width on the fly based on scaled image width

Tags: javascript, css

I want to have the page adjust the width of the div that surrounds an image with a little text underneath it, such that the text is forced to wrap so as not to exceed the width of the image. The thumb's width will vary from thumb to thumb. In the code below, I've identified the unknown width with "???".

```
<div id="N-03-item" style="float:left; width: ???;">
  <p><a href="item.php?i=8">
  <img id="N-03" src="photos/thumbs/8.jpg" alt='Choker Necklace 18"'/><br/>
  Frosted Flower Choker Necklace 18"</a></p>
</div>
```

I presume this is something that needs to happen with javascript (although a CSS solution would also be good), but javascript is not my strength. The resulting div width will need to be different each time, based on what the DOM reports the image width to be in each instance.

Can someone tell me what the appropriate javascript would be?

Comment: You could bring in a little more pride into your question by stripping out the unneccessary parts. Not just copy the code you have. This tells us, you thought before you asked

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) It woould be something like:

```
$("#N-03-item").css({
     "width": $("#N-03").width()
});
```

Comment: You can do that in the onready event of the page, but isn't there a change for the image not be loaded causing the width not be correctly returned?

Comment: Yes there is. Especialy if images are loaded dynamicaly. But when the image loads, wouldn't the div ignore "width" and spread to the image size?

Answer (score 1):

OK, you don't have to use JavaScript for this. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jeykeu/WCHcP/2/

**UPDATE:**

OK, @sanitycheck now I did it with jQuery. Check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jeykeu/2dBJa/2 I hope it help

Comment: This won't work for me. I don't want to set a max-width at a predetermined fixed size. I want the width of the div to be derived from the width of the instance of the image.

Comment: In any case, I guess a div with max-width attribute will help.
Why don't you try @Voooza's answer and mine combined.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete working example. The width of the DIV is adjusted as soon as an image has finished loading. Which can be as early as the domready event. No need to wait until document.onload fires.  I slightly improved your markup, getting rid of the BR tag. (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web5me/7dTFd/))

css

```
.link-thumb { float: left; border: 1px solid gold; position: relative; }
.link-thumb img { display: block; }
.desc { position: absolute; }
```

html

```
<div class="link-thumb" id="id">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="thumb" id="id" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="foo" width="100" height="100" />
        <span class="desc">Frosted Flower Choker Necklace 18"</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.thumb').on('load', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('.link-thumb').width( $this.width() );
});
```

If you're not using jQuery 1.7+ substitute the `.on` method with the `.bind` method!

Edit: I incorporated dave's CSS only solution. So this script only needs to run for IE7 and older! However, depending on your use case, you may now have to set a fixed height on .link-thumb as the .desc is now not part of the flow.

Comment: dave's solution is elegant and correct — but will fail in IE7 and older.

Comment: Instead of $this.parents('.link-thumb') I recommend $this.closest('.link-thumb') because parents could theoretically return more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these assumptions:

- You are not able to access the width of the image, and set that width on the containing DIV through server code
- You'll be able to reserve enough space for line wrapping, since solution uses absolute positioning and takes text out of the flow

I would try:

```
#N-03-item {
    position : relative;  
}

/* if you can add a class for items, in addition to ID (e.g. N-03-item) than use a  
   rule such as 

.item {
     position :relative
 }

 */

 .description{
      position : absolute;
 }
```

Description is positioned absolutely, but there is no top or left specified.  *Most* user agents will try to position the .description element where it *should have* appeared. This will cause the width of the description to get bound by the width of the item DIV (which itself is shrunk to fit the width of the image since it is floated left).

I think you still need to sort out reserving enough space below the item if there are items following it, the text is taken out of the flow.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/5FJvd/